# Using Tableau - SIde by Side bar chart along with 3 measures

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 measures - sales($), profit($) and discount (%). I want to show Sales and Profit as side by side chart over time and discount as a line chart (all 3 in one).

Is there any way to do this. On tableau community i found some useful tips but for that ill need to pivot the data. I want to avoid doing that.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Aniket

Comment: Fabio's answer will certainly help, yet you can create side by side bar chart if data structure is in proper shape. Can you please share the data structure

Answer (score 0):

As you have already pointed out, in order to have side by side barchart combined with a line chart is quite tricky and needs a transformation of data.

Anyway, if you can accept to have a barchart inside the other one (say profit "inside" sales) like the following, you can get it in few clicks using measure names and dual axis.

[image]

If needed, I've even find a really [good tutorial by Andy Kriebel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKQjN3-HpII):